# Format the xml data to store into Mongo collection using Golang

Tags: json, xml, mongodb, go

Need to read the large xml files and format those and store in the mongo collection.

Which is the best way from below

1. Read large xml files and format it and directly store in the mongodb collection.
2. Read large xml files and convert that to json and store it in the mongodb collection.

Comment: I think we need more informations in what you really wanna do

Comment: @Wariored : I want to parse the xml data and store in the mongo collection.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the two options above, the best way is to just read the XML files and store into MongoDB collection. This is because MongoDB does not store data in JSON format, but in [Binary JSON (BSON)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON).

You can write a simple script utilising [encoding/xml](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/) library to read XML files, then encode into [mongo-driver/bson](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson) to insert into MongoDB collections.